# How to extract certain portion of text file?

Tags: python

I am working with multiple text files and I want to extract all the notes from the files and print it to another output text file. The text file that I am reading looks something as follows:

```
This is the first line of the text file
Second Line
Third Line
Note 1: Warning, there seems to be an error..............
continuation line of Note 1.

Note 2: Another warning, blah blah...............
continuation line of Note 2

Note 3: Third warning, fix this issue immediately..............
continuation line of Note 3.

This is the end of the text file
```

I want to extract only the lines that have the notes. All files have different lines preceding the notes section but always have the `This is the end of the text file` line after the notes. My approach is something as follows:

```
input_file = open('input.txt', 'r')
fh  = open('output.txt', 'w')
for line in my_file:
    if line.startswith('Note'):
        fh.write(line)
```

This approach only grabs the lines that start with 'Note'. But, I want to be able to extract all the lines of all the notes.

Comment: How do you know what belongs to a note? I.e. when does a note end?

Comment: The notes can be random. But like I said, once the notes end, there is an empty line and `This is the end of the text file` line immediately below. I was thinking about using regular expressions with `Note` as starting pattern and `This is the end of the text file` as the stopping pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each note is terminated by an empty line, you could do something like this:

```
in_note = False

for line in my_file:
    if line.startswith('Note'):
        in_note = True
    elif line.strip() == '':
        in_note = False

    if in_note:
        fh.write(line)
```